# UICollectionView under Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UINavigationBar`, a `UIToolbar` and a `UICollectionView`.

Everything was working fine until a few days ago but now the `UICollectionViewCells` are displayed under the navigation bar and over the toolbar(i.e. the toolbar is not displayed).

Is there a way to setup the `UICollectionView` correctly so that all the components(navigation bar, collection view and toolbar) are displayed?

Comment: can you also post an image

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes I'm using autolayout. I'll post a screenshot this evening.

Comment: @franswa set y co-ordinate of collection view properly...

Comment: The UICollection view must me drawing on top of the UIToolbar due to view order or the UIToolbar could be drawing itself off frame. I suggest you print out the list of subviews and frames of the parent view to figure out where the root of the problem is.

Comment: Ok the UICollectionView must be the first component from the list. If the collection view is under the toolbar then it is not displayed correctly.